# Could not railties in mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I had recently followed multiple blogs to completely wipe out rvm, rails and then reinstalled ruby 2.3.0 and rails 5. Made and app using it no issues. But the moment I opened a new terminal window in my machine it was not recognising rails at all as if it was only installed in that particular terminal.

So I just completed my work in that single terminal. Now when I restarted my laptop, I am unable to run the same app. I do not wish to reinstall everything again as I am sure this is a small configuration problem. Why is this happening?

The error message that I am getting now:

```
/Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0.a) among 30 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I have already seen other similar questions where they ask to reinstall everything again which I do not want to do as it worked after installing but did not work on system restart.

Now I did `gem install rails` in one terminal and the app is working again, but if I try to open a new terminal and give the same command `rails s`, it gives me this error,

```
Ignoring byebug-9.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.5
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.8
Ignoring byebug-9.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.5
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
/Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/io-console-0.4.6/lib/io/console.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/sahil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from /Users/sahil/Documents/work/Development/todoApp/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please include commands that you run in the examples.

Comment: Now to temporary fix the issue, I first have to use this command: `rvm use 2.3.1` and then `gem install rails`. But this command only helps me in running rails related command in that particular terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you reinstalled ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 5. However it seems rbenv is trying to load your project with ruby 2.3.1.
You should switch to ruby 2.3.0. I guess you should be able to do: `rbenv local 2.3.0`.
To avoid this from happening again though, you should add a `.ruby-version` dotfile to your project root and in the file only add `2.3.0`.

Hope that works

Comment: If I run this `rbenv local 2.3.0`, it says `version `2.3.0' not installed`. For running the app I have to do `gem install rails again and again`. The setup is getting lost.

Comment: could you run `ruby -v`?

Comment: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]`.

Comment: Could you open another terminal and run it again on the new terminal?

Comment: Same message 2.3.0 is not installed. Ruby version is same as mentioned above 2.3.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116901/discussion-between-oreoluwa-and-sahil).